# R and Simmer: Performance boost on large data frames

Tags: c++, r, simulation

I've got on own dataframe on actual events/task and I use the simmer r package to simulate how many task can be done if different resources were available. My simulation runs very fast up to 120.000 rows within my dataframe.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(dplyr)
library(simmer)
library(simmer.plot)

load("task_df.RDATA")

working_hours <- 7.8
productivity <- 0.7
no.employees <- 292

SIM_TIME <- round((working_hours*productivity*60), 0)+1

employees <- vector("character")

for (i in 1:no.employees) {
  employees[i] <- paste("employee", i, sep="_")
}

taskTraj <- trajectory(name = "tasK simulation") %>%
  simmer::select(resources = employees, policy = "shortest-queue") %>%
  seize_selected(amount = 1) %>%
  timeout_from_attribute("duration") %>%
  release_selected(amount = 1)


arrivals_gen <- simmer() 

for (i in 1:no.employees) {arrivals_gen %>%
    add_resource(paste("employee", i, sep="_"), capacity = 1) 
} 

ptm <- proc.time()

arrivals_gen <- arrivals_gen %>%
  add_dataframe("Task_", taskTraj, task_df, mon = 2, col_time = "time", time = "absolute",  col_priority="priority")  %>%
  run(SIM_TIME)

proc.time() - ptm
```

But my dataframe tasK_df contains 350k datasets and thats the point where my simulation takes a lot of more time.

head(task_df, n = 50)

```
workload_shift  task_id duration priority time
1        20180403 68347632        3    2.502    0
2        20180403 68151881       10   24.478    0
3        20180403 68069718        3    0.724    0
4        20180403 68345621        4    2.226    0
5        20180403 68508858        3   36.062    0
6        20180403 66148996        3    9.421    0
7        20180403 68565066        2   24.478    0
8        20180403 68005344        3    7.910    0
9        20180403 55979902        3    3.732    0
10       20180403 66452138        2    2.502    0
11       20180403 68051869       10    2.226    0
12       20180403 68561364       10    3.584    0
13       20180403 59292591        3    2.138    0
14       20180403 68415657       10    2.853    0
15       20180403 66848400        3    2.290    0
16       20180403 68454851       10    6.167    0
17       20180403 68361846       10   11.688    0
18       20180403 68572723        2    6.259    0
19       20180403 68520328        2   24.478    0
20       20180403 68500955       10    1.855    0
21       20180403 67000753        3  219.751    0
22       20180403 68487613        3    8.131    0
23       20180403 68333674        4    5.263    0
24       20180403 66423486        3    2.290    0
25       20180403 68241616        5    1.470    0
26       20180403 68415001        4    3.584    0
27       20180403 67487967        3    2.636    0
28       20180403 68494771       10    6.259    0
29       20180403 67673981       10    2.226    0
30       20180403 68355727        3    2.613    0
31       20180403 36942995        3    0.590    0
32       20180403 66633446        3    5.968    0
33       20180403 68461510        2   24.478    0
34       20180403 67126138        3    0.357    0
35       20180403 68485682        3    8.131    0
36       20180403 67852953       10    2.290    0
37       20180403 68150106       10    6.259    0
38       20180403 67833053       10    4.114    0
39       20180403 67816673        3    6.259    0
40       20180403 68041431        5    2.502    0
41       20180403 66283761        5    2.502    0
42       20180403 68543314        2   26.302    0
43       20180403 68492843        3    2.290    0
44       20180403 68556960        4    2.853    0
45       20180403 66885335        3    5.975    0
46       20180403 66249231        5    2.636    0
47       20180403 68242565       12    1.470    0
48       20180403 68530355        2    2.290    0
49       20180403 66683717        5    5.705    0
50       20180403 67802538        4    0.864    0
```

user  system elapsed
 76.745   0.039  76.717

vs

user  system elapsed 
608.443   0.270 608.186

[My CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87jhW.png)

Is there a way to boost my simulation? I use simmer 4.1.0 and Rcpp 1.0.0. Memory doesnt seems to be an issue.

Comment: Based on your code above, I tried dataframes with 100k and 1M observations (with random data) and I see no performance issues (i.e., 1M takes x10 the time of 100k rows, as expected). Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @IñakiÚcar Thanks in advance for your fast reply. I have updated my code snippet above to give a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your table and simply replicated it to build 100k and 400k datasets, and I confirm the issue: the execution time is not linear.

Internally, attributes are always `double`, so there are lots of conversions, row by row, which apparently take most of the execution time (!). Try converting your table before feeding it into `simmer`. Using `dplyr`,

```
task_df <- mutate_all(task_df, as.double)
```

The simulation should be much faster, and the execution time for increasing number of rows should grow more or less linearly. It's evident why so many casts are degrading the performance, though I'm not sure why it makes execution time non-linear.

Anyway, in future releases, we may want to apply this automatically, so that the user doesn't have to bother about these performance issues.

Comment: Thank you! it worked very well and it seems to be linear!